# Open file with App on iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I open a file (it's an XML file) with the iOS app I'm developing. I want to test my: `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` implementation. How do I do this? iOS Simulator doesn't come with Mail or anything so I'm clueless as to testing that kind of a function.
Any ideas?

I did Document Types under Xcode's Target Properties bit so I'm pretty sure that's right:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>icon</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>XML File</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.XML</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: Put the file on a web server and access the link using Safari in the simulator.

Comment: It wont show up there. It only shows up Facebook and everything else but my app. I know its not my code because I have read the tutorial in and out.

Comment: Unless of corse it needs to be specific code to open with Safari but I dont think thats the case.

Comment: You post the relevant entry from the Info.plist file. You may have it wrong.

Comment: Build the file into your app.

Comment: @rmaddy done. Edited it into the thread

Comment: @HotLicks I believe the point is that the app should be able to open any XML file.

Comment: Create a second app that uses UIDocumentInteractionController

Comment: It may be an old question but I would try UIWebView which can render pdf for sure and hopefully render xml too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something that looks like this:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>XML File</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.xml</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This should be one entry in the Info.plist file.

Answer (score 8):

You simply have to drag and drop your file on the simulator. If your app registers for that file type, your app will open and handle it.

Comment: Given that I just spent 3 days messing around with webservers, iCloud Drive, emails and even 3rd party apps to try and do just this with no success, this answer is well worthy of it's upvote. Thank you good sir.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [sample application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple, you can include your file in this app and it will let you do an 'open in' where you can select your app.